# Is there a way to clear an array and basically reset it to its past contents

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

i basically want to reset an array once i have shot all the elements in my array/game. is there a way i can clear my 2D array and basically reset it so that all the elements i have shot and declared null then return?

Comment: only by keeping an array reference of the original contents and reassigning it (Note you might need deep copies depending on the class of the array)

Comment: please add what you have tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Create an array in its initial state and just deep copy it every time you want to start / re-start the game. Don't ever change it. You could have a static method that returns it, in a factory way.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a (deep) copy of the original array, and at the end just make a new working copy of it.

If you're not making changes to the actual objects inside the array, you could just do a shallow copy with `Foo[][] backup = original.clone();`, but if the objects in the array have state (for example health), you'll need to loop the array by hand and create deep copies of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear array by Loop over the array and and set each element to null.

```
for( int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++ )
   Arrays.fill( yourArray[i], null );
```

you cannot restore past contents except you can make backup (Copy) of your array for later use.

Deep Copy Code:

```
public int[][] copy(int[][] input) {
      int[][] target = new int[input.length][];
      for (int i=0; i <input.length; i++) {
        target[i] = Arrays.copyOf(input[i], input[i].length);
      }
      return target;
}
```

Comment: yourArray means your array object

Comment: okay thanks and how would i make a copy of my array? is it just a simple copy and paste of the loop i already have?